# How to replace a dot with a string in a python list

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
my_list = ['b','.','.']

expected_list = ['b','.','w']
```

May be simple, moving into python recently so any suggestions would be fine

Comment: you are only changing one of your dots to a character. What exactly is the criteria you are replacing on? Is this for just one value? Do you have any code you can share to help clarify?

Comment: @idjaw i am just trying to replace the last element

Comment: `my_list[-1] = 'w'`? Or are you trying to replace the last element only if it is a `'.'`?

Comment: @idjaw am sorry not the last element, will traverse through the list if i encounter a '.' then replace it with 'w'

Comment: Please edit your question with the exact criteria you are looking replace dots with a character. Also, please show what you have attempted to solve this.

Comment: You already have the desired output. If you want to create that second list algorithmically, you will have to explain what algorithm you'd like to use, then try to implement it yourself, do independent research, etc., and _then_ post a question.

Comment: Your question is not clear. As @idjaw commented, please mention what's your exact criteria of replacing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are replacing every occurrence of '.' with 'w' then I would just suggest:

```
for n, i in enumerate(my_list):
    if i == '.':
        my_list[n] = 'w'
```

Here is the documentation for how to use the enumerate() function: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate

Answer (score 1):

> You can do this by using list comprehension also

```
l = ['w' if i == '.' else i for i in my_list]
```